# CNAME records and dns cache

Tags: caching, dns, bind, cname, nameservers

Say we have 2 sites foo.com and bar.com
They are located on the same server zzz.xxx.ccc.vvv
They got A records on my BIND server(that is also same server) pointing to zzz.xxx.ccc.vvv
For a moment foo.com is empty.
I misinterpreted a task and made a CNAME record like

foo.com   IN   CNAME    bar.com

So I accidentally mirrored site and got duplicate content at foo.com and bar.com
As soon as I realized it, I removed CNAME record but 24 hours later i still go to foo.com and get bar.com content. 
Maybe I did something wrong?(besides CNAME thing).
It refreshed to a new CNAME state in 4 hours. Dig shows no CNAME records already. But somewhere deleted record is still cached. How long can it take to refresh it to the old state? And what can I do to make sure everything is right from my side? I'm new to DNS configuration, but still need to do it right.

Comment: Suspicion #1: you forgot to update the SOA serial number, so the secondary servers aren't reloading the zone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did forgot to update it but increased serial by 1 as sson as realized it. dig soa shows current serial. I dont understand why is cname record still up. It is deleted from bar.com zone file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved! It was not clear to me, but apache's vhosts were missing this site.